# Which class does this RIL SIMPBD refers in the "I/RIL SIMPBD( 1409): [1409] debug, main: entered"

Tags: android, ril

```
I/RIL SIMPBD( 1409): [1409] debug, main: entered
I/RIL SIMPBD( 1409): [1409] info, await_modem_powered_on: Wait to be triggered...
I/RIL SIMPBD( 1409): [1409] info, await_modem_powered_on: SIM_PHONEBOOK Normal startup...
I/RIL SIMPBD( 1409): [1409] info, await_modem_powered_on: triggered
I/RIL_MAL ( 1405): NETLNK_LIB::Entering function netlnk_socket_create
I/RIL_MAL ( 1405): NETLNK_LIB::Create Netlink  Socket...
I/RIL_MAL ( 1405): NETLNK_LIB::(fn: netlnk_socket_create)::SUCCESS
```

Please help me out what does this `RIL SIMPBD` means? ,i.e is to which class it refers?
I will be even more thankful if any of you can tell which class to `RIL_MAL` refers?

Answer (score 0):

All these are tags defined in hardware section .
WRT to Ril.C and Ril.Cpp